# MPPT input current measurement

Tags: stm32, embedded, solar-cell, mppt

I am currently working on building an MPPT, in a synchronous buck configuration. The HW side is almost done, I am still figuring out the current measurement and doing some tests to see how current sensors perform.
The target is to have an MPPT that charges a 12V Li-Ion battery that I built.
The issue I am facing now is regarding the input current measurement synchronization. I am planning to have 2 current sensors, one on the input and one on the output. The one on the output is pretty easy to handle since the current is almost every time a positive value and only going to 0A when the battery is fully charged.

The input sensor on the other side, sees the peak current when the high-side FET is switched ON and when the high-side FET switches OFF, the current goes directly to 0. My question here is, should I synchronize the current measurement with the state of the high-side FET or is averaging on multiple samples enough to obtain a good value?
For control, I am using an STM32 Nucleo board for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do MPPT, then you can just us the output current -- since that is the current (power) you are trying to maximize.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I would use two sensors so I can have the input overview on the display as well.